# Flutter Build iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I try to build a flutter app for ios.

After flutter build ios i get these two errors:

- Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
- No profiles for 'com.mybundle' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.mybundle'. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Open the project in Xcode. And fix the errors there. As I recall you have to choose the Runner in Xcode and then signing and capabilities in there choose the team and then run the app.

Comment: Thats what I did. I need a provisioning profile. Do I need a physical iPhone to register such a provisioning profile with a device?

Comment: Yeah I guess. The error says " Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it."